# GitLab parent-child pipelines connectors glitches

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was trying to build CI/CD pipeline on GitLab CE that would use parent-child feature, the result was ok from the functional point of view, but there were some weird GUI bugs that I figured were caused by some bad yml coding on my part. I've looked in the documentation and basically used their code, I was about to plug my scripts and extend from there, but the basic docs example is buggy as well. Has anyone experienced similar issues? Here is how it looks like:
[image]

The code:
.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
    stages:
        - build
        - test
        - deploy
    
    job1:
        script: echo "Building..."
        only: 
            - feature/parent-child-testing
        stage: build
    
    microservice_a:
        stage: test
        only: 
            - feature/parent-child-testing
        trigger:
            include: build/pipelines/testa.yml
    
    microservice_b:
        stage: test
        only: 
            - feature/parent-child-testing
        trigger:
            include: build/pipelines/testb.yml
    
    microservice_c:
        stage: test
        only: 
            - feature/parent-child-testing
        trigger:
            include: build/pipelines/testc.yml
            
    job2:
        stage: deploy
        only: 
            - feature/parent-child-testing
        script: echo "Building..."
```

testa.yml/testb.yml/testc.yml:

```yaml
    stages:
        - build
        - test
        - deploy
    
    build_job_1:
        stage: build
        script: echo "Running build job"
        
    build_job_2:
        stage: build
        script: echo "Running build job"
        
    build_job_3:
        stage: build
        script: echo "Running build job"
        
    snapshot_1:
        stage: test
        script: echo "Running test job"
        
    snapshot_2:
        stage: test
        script: echo "Running test job"
        
    snapshot_3:
        stage: test
        script: echo "Running test job"
    
    deploy_1:
        stage: deploy
        script: echo "Running deploy job"
        
    deploy_2:
        stage: deploy
        script: echo "Running deploy job"
        
    deploy_3:
        stage: deploy
        script: echo "Running deploy job"
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: @DV82XL unfortunately no, I didn't have time to play with it more. Deeper analysis of that bug is somewhere deep in the backlog on the project I work for ;d